# Adicionar valor no inicio e no fim de uma string em mysql

Tags: mysql, concatenação-de-string

Como adicionar texto no início e no fim de uma string?

Por exemplo, gostaria de adicionar `<p style="display:inline;">` no início e `</p>` no fim de todas as linhas da coluna `answer` na tabela `question_answer`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode usar a função `CONCAT`.

Para concatenar a informação **antes** do valor atual, você pode usar:

```
UPDATE question_answer SET answer = CONCAT('<p style="display:inline;">', answer );
```

Para adicionar informação **depois** do valor atual:

```
UPDATE question_answer SET answer = CONCAT(answer, '</p>');
```